# How to check if a checkbox was checked in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm pulling a list of items from table database and checkbox to check and approve each item; however even when I check the item it throws this error message : Please select at least one requested item. What I'm trying to achieve is that the user checks any amount of items in the list and then the status requisition number is updated to 0.

```
 public ActionResult RequisitionList(List<Requisition> postingObj)

    {

        IssueDAO dbObj = new DAO(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        List<string> reqNumbers = new List<string>();
        bool check=false;


        foreach (var item in postingObj)
        {
            if (item.postTrnx)
            {
                reqNumbers.Add(item.reqNumber);
            }

        }

        if (check == true)
        {
            dbObj.SetRequisitionStatus0(reqNumbers);
            ViewBag.Message = "Approval Successful!";

        }
        else {
            ViewBag.Message = "Please select at least one requested item";
            return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
        }
        return View(dbObj.GetAllRequest());
    }

 public void SetRequisitionStatus0(List<string> reqNumbers)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "requisition_sp_setstatus0";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters.Add("@approve_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        using (command.Connection = connection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                foreach (var item in reqNumbers)
                {
                    command.Parameters["@reqNumber"].Value = item;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return;

    }


    public List<Requisition> GetAllRequest()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("getallrequests", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                List<Requisition> request = new List<Requisition>();

                SqlDataReader rdrObj;

                connection.Open();
                rdrObj = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdrObj.Read())
                {
                    Requisition requisition = new Requisition();


                    requisition.reqNumber = rdrObj.GetString(0);
                    requisition.reqDate = rdrObj.GetDateTime(1);

                   requisition.items = getRequestItemByRquisition(rdrObj.GetString(0));
                    request.Add(requisition);
                }
                rdrObj.Close();


                return request;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Haven't touched asp in 10 years, but I see nothing here changing the value of bool check from false to true before you test it. That is, you set it to false, then checked if it was true.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change it